# How to deal with "<?" annotation in xml file with Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xquery, processing-instruction

Somebody know how to deal with this kind of XML annotation with Python, it's my first time I saw this.

```
&lt;?link id="752760" resource-uuid="UUID-9f0575a3-1847-1cde-fd35-f18014fdecf3" resource-id="570935" resource-type="fork" type="ResourceLink"?&gt;
```

I need to query this kind of 'element' to get the `resource-uuid` value.

Comment: use [xml module](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/xml) or similar

Comment: I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` but when I do the parse, I don't see this values in `children`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everybody, I learned about the processing instruction and with this, I did a research about how to deal with it, bellow I let my scratch if anybody would need it:

```py
from lxml import etree

...

file = 'path/to/file.xml'
tree = etree.parse(file)
result = tree.xpath('//processing-instruction("link")')
for pi in result:
    # Each pi is a processing instruction tagged as 'link'
    if pi.get('type').__str__() == 'ResourceImport':
        # PI with type = ResourceImport
        print pi.text # Check the text of tis PI
```

Using `lxml` library is easy to get the processing instructions using XPath.

I hope this code snippet helps to people who get here because of this question.

Comment: Thx for sharing this. It is very kind of you to say *Thanks to everybody*, but people won't get any notice. Therefore one hint: It is a good idea to close this queston by accepting one answer. This can be your own answer, or the one which helped you most. Once you've reached the 15 points border yourself it would be nice to come back and vote on any helpful answer. That's the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You must distinguish between a *processing instruction* and the *xml declaration*

Both are written in the same way: `<?SomeName SomeContent ?>`.

Find [details in section 2.6](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/)!

While the xml-declaration must be in the first place and starts with `<?xml` other processing instructions might appear (almost) anywhere in the XML.

A processing instruction must have a name, while the content is not formally restricted like an element's content. It is free text...

So this is well-formed XML:

```
<root>
  <a>test</a>
  <?piName some test?>
</root>
```

I do not work with python, but this would return your PI in SQL-Server:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
    <a>test</a>
    <?link id="752760" resource-uuid="UUID-9f0575a3-1847-1cde-fd35-f18014fdecf3" resource-id="570935" resource-type="fork" type="ResourceLink"?>
  </root>';

SELECT @xml.query('/root/processing-instruction("link")');
```

Even if your content looks like *attributes*: Within the PI the content is free text. So you have to parse your information out of the content...

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16080234/5089204) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports XQuery 3.1, here is one way to solve the problem:

```
declare function local:values($pi) {
  map:merge(
    for $pair in tokenize($pi)
    let $key := substring-before($pair, '=')
    let $value := replace(substring-after($pair, '='), '^"|"$', '')
    return map:entry($key, $value)
  )
};

let $xml := document {
  <xml>
    <?link id="752760" resource-uuid="UUID-9f0575a3-1847-1cde-fd35-f18014fdecf3"
      resource-id="570935" resource-type="fork" type="ResourceLink"?>
  </xml>
}
for $pi in $xml//processing-instruction('link')
let $values := local:values($pi)
return $values?resource-uuid
```

One more solution for older versions of XQuery:

```
let $xml := document {
  <xml>
    <?link id="752760" resource-uuid="UUID-9f0575a3-1847-1cde-fd35-f18014fdecf3"
      resource-id="570935" resource-type="fork" type="ResourceLink"?>
  </xml>
}
for $pi in $xml//processing-instruction('link')
for $pair in tokenize($pi, '\s+')[substring-before(., '=') = 'resource-uuid']
return replace(substring-after($pair, '='), '^"|"$', '')
```

Both code snippets work under the assumption that the values in your processing instructions are all composed as in your example (keys and values separated with equal sign, values wrapped with double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

The "annotation" you refer to is called a [processing instruction](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi).

It's very common in processing instructions to use a `keyword="value"` syntax similar to the attributes of an XML element, but unfortunately this is only a convention, not something intrinsic to XML, so you'll have to parse the content yourself to extract the attributes. (Saxon has a function [`saxon:get-pseudo-attribute()`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/get-pseudo-attribute.html) for this).

If you're in Python it's probably simpler to do this extra stage of parsing in Python code rather than XPath code -- unless you actually need the value as part of some larger XPath expression, in which case the detail depends on whether you are using XPath or XQuery and which version.